# Why is k8s Ingress (nginx controller) only returning a portion of my served webpage?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to deploy a webserver using React, Nginx to serve the static React files, Docker to containerize the React + Nginx, Kubernetes to deploy, and Ingress (using Nginx again as my Ingress controller) to route HTTP calls to the pods. For simplicity, I am just using the default React template (`npx create-react-project`) as the entirety of my webpage.

I am able to containerize and serve my template React page successfully. I can access it both in the container (via running the container via `docker run` and forwarding the port) and k8s deployment (via a NodePort on an attached service to this deployment). Everything renders on the browser when served from these two sanity checks.

However, when I hook up Ingress my page refuses to render in the browser. It is just blank.

I did a little bit of comparison, and I am seeing that when accessing the Ingress route my browser is getting the index HTML page, but is missing the media, node_modules, webpack, and manifest.json folders (which exist in my properly rendering container page).

Does anyone have any ideas on why my Ingress is not returning these resources when accessed? I am guessing this is why my page is not rendering

Below is my `ingress.yaml` for reference:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations: 
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: my-site.info
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: frontend-service
              port:
                number: 3000
```

Comment: What is this annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1` doing? And please open `developer mode` (Inspect or hit `F12`) and see what pages get errors like `404`.

Comment: I had taken that annotation from another codebase -- they are the only lines I didn't really understand in the whole codebase. This is my first Kubernetes project. 

I just took out the line and gave it a rerun and everything is rendering now! Thanks, not sure what about that annotation made it break.

Comment: Apparently it rewrites the route such that it matches regular expressions you can use to define your routing paths. In my case I wasn't using any regex, so it didn't belong there.